# React-admin additional item in dataProvider returned Object

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

dataProvider on `GET_LIST`

```
return {
  data: someData,
  total: total,
}
```

I want something like this:

```
return {
  data,
  total,
  myCustomParam: 'param'
}
```

When i add myCustomParam it's just disappears
I can't find it out